# Better alternative to pinging the database over and over?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, fetch

I want to create a dashboard that automatically updates when new data is posted.
My first thought was to just make a javascript function and put a fetch statement in it and then loop the function every second or every couple of seconds...

Obviously, this is not a great solution.  But I don't know what the better way is...

Some notes:

-PHP Server-Side Language

-Ran on Localhost so traffic is not going over the internet

Can anyone advise what I should be doing or if this is an acceptable approach?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can try using websockets

Comment: MySQl have no any built-in notification service. Either poll or search for external module which will register some user-defined notification function applied in a trigger.

Comment: you need something like publish and subscribe thing

Comment: @Someone_who_likes_SE What are websockets?  The other two comments meant nothing to me....I am lost...

Comment: websockets can be used to connect to a server. it constantly listens for messages from the server. [more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API)

Comment: Please look into Websockets, SocketIO or SSE

Answer (score 1):

Server Side:

- You can look for any *onUpdate* events if your database supports any such events
- Or else just run a query in a timed interval to fetch new updates form the database *(Connection to database is made just once and all subsequent requests go through the same connection. Hence this isn't a bad approach)*

But when it comes to client side and receiving those updates, you can make it efficient in either of the two ways:

- [Simple] Use Socket IO - Push an event with your new data and listen to them on the client side. *(This way socket connection is made just once and all subsequent responses are received in the same connection)*
  Docs: https://socket.io/docs/v4/index.html
- [Complex] Use HTTP stream
  Example: https://gist.github.com/igrigorik/5736866

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I am going to look into Socket IO in the morning.